# How to make an optional property with a default value in Zod

Tags: typescript, zod

I'm using [Zod](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod) and I want to define one schema for user input that has an optional field with a default value.
However, it is being impossible for me to make the runtime behaviour match the inferred type.
What I want, is the field to be optional, and when not provided, or provided as undefined, use the default value. If I want this behaviour I can't have the field optional in the generated type, and if I manage to make it optional in the generated type, then it will not get a default value during runtime.

Let me explain it with code:

```
import { Timestamp } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { z } from 'zod';

export const someSchema = z.object({
  id: z.string(),
  timestamp: z.instanceof(Timestamp),
  type: z.enum(['fever', 'constipation']),
  notes: z.string().optional().default(''),
});

export const someInput = someSchema
  .omit({ id: true })
  .merge(
    z.object({
      timestamp: z
        .date()
        .optional()
        .default(() => new Date()),
    }),
  )
  .partial({
    notes: true,
  });

export const schemaArray = z.array(someSchema);

export type Schema = z.infer<typeof someSchema>;
export type SchemaInput = z.infer<typeof someInput>; // <- Here I expect timestamp to be optional, but it is required


function a({ type, timestamp, notes}: SchemaInput){
  someInput.parse({
  type, timestamp, notes
  })
}

a({type: 'fever'}) <- Error, timestamp is required
```

Answer (score 16):

As I was [pointed out on github](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod/issues/1230#issuecomment-1167244200) schemas usually have an input and an output type. By default, what `z.infer` does is returning the output type, which is probably the most common usage scenario. Thankfully there is also a method to extract the expected input for the parser, and that is exactly what I needed:

```
export type SchemaInput = z.input<typeof someInput>;

function a({ type, timestamp, notes}: SchemaInput){
  someInput.parse({
  type, timestamp, notes
  })
```

Now the inferred schema looks like this:

```
type SchemaInput = {
    timestamp?: Date | undefined;
    notes?: string | undefined;
    type: "fever" | "constipation";
}
```

Which is exactly what I needed for a function that takes this input and uses the validator to ensure it has the proper format.

Comment: Edit: You want to use `z.input<typeof someInput>` or `z.output<typeof someInput>` instead of `z.infer`.

Comment: So do you need type to have `undefined` because this way you can use it in the function that will receive the raw inputs and than parse it? If so, I would say a better ideia would use type  `unknow` to functions param since you really don't know if it is from type.