# Zod - Using optional() with default() infers the wrong type

Tags: node.js, typescript, zod

I'm using Zod with a field that is optional, but has a default value set, however, the inferred type says it could be undefined, even though it has a default value

```
const Schema = z.object({
  page: z.number().positive().optional().default(1)
})

type SchemaType = z.infer<typeof Schema>
// page?: number | undefined;
```

I tried using `z.input` and `z.output`, but they don't work either.

Is this intentional or is there another infer helper, which infers the parsed result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make an optional property with a default value in Zod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72771130/how-to-make-an-optional-property-with-a-default-value-in-zod)

Comment: It seems like the issue is the same, but the solution is not very ergonomic, it uses multiple composed types. I cant use z.input on Schema, because that would make all of the optional fields optional in TS. I need a type based on the runtime output of the schema, but z.output does not infer that one properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you enabled strict mode in your `tsconfig.json`? [It's not enabled by default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) (the default value for `--strict` is `false`) but [Zod's installation requirements](https://zod.dev/?id=requirements) say that it must be enabled:

> - TypeScript 4.5+!
> - You must enable strict mode in your `tsconfig.json`. This is a best practice for all TypeScript projects.
>
>   ```json
>   // tsconfig.json
>   {
>     // ...
>     "compilerOptions": {
>       // ...
>       "strict": true
>     }
>   }
>   ```

On my machine, using your code and the latest version of Zod (v3.21.4), `SchemaType` is inferred as:

- `{ page: number }` when strict mode is enabled.
- `{ page?: number }` when strict mode is disabled.